# WPF: Changing button background and font is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of button in a `StackPanel`. Those buttons allow me to switch between different usercontrols. When one button is pressed, I want the button style to change so that the user can know which button is active. To achieve this, I have implemented a style trigger that switches the background color as well as the text font on click or on MouseOver. Here is the code:

```xml
<Button Uid="0" Width="120" Content="Manage" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" 
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="DemiBold" Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>                    
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
<Button Uid="1" Width="120" Content="Settings" Height="50" Background="{x:Null}" 
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontWeight="DemiBold" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

However, this code does not work and I can't figure out why.

I have seen multiple questions with the same problem and it seems like I am doing it right but somehow, when I run the app, the styling does not work. Any clue as of why?

Comment: "Manage" button works correctly while the button is pressed.
If be MouseUp state comes back to the original state. Therefore if you clicked the "Manage" button then button looks like is not working.
If you want to change appearance of the button when clicked then you should use the ToggleButton rather than Button.

Comment: Why can't you try using [ToggleButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton).

Comment: You should read about value precedence: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much simpler if you will using `RadioButton` and apply style from `ToggleButton`. Then you can use the property `IsChecked` to style your button.

Please look at my example:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="MenuButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
          <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                  <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <RadioButton  Uid="0" Width="120" Content="Manage" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}"/>
  <RadioButton  Uid="1" Width="120" Content="Settings" Height="50" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. But only for the background color. The font weight, borderbrush and borderthickness did not change on click

Comment: @BrunoBukavuThai sorry my friend it was my mistake. You should use in this case RelativeSource in binding expression. Please check my answer again :)

Comment: Works perfect now. Thank @kmatyaszek